# Public API check for Kotlin libraries

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm writing a small Kotlin library right now and wondered whether there is a way to validate which classes and functions are publicly exposed.

I basically want to ensure the library does not expose any implementation details that are not ment to be part of the public API.

As of now I denote everything as `internal` whenever the library user should not be able to access the given class / function.
The issue with this approach is that I may forget to declare something as `internal` and thus expose something to the user.

I would like to get a warning / error on build time when I expose a class / method not on purpose.

Any hints on how to achieve this or best practice highly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kotlin 1.4-M2 introduced the [explicit API mode](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/06/kotlin-1-4-m2-released/#explicit-api-mode), which feels like what you're looking for. Explicit API mode requires you to add the `public` visibility modifier to all public APIs and specify return types explicitly. You can configure the Gradle plugin to either warn you about explicit API mode violations, or even fail the build.

This feature is available since [Kotlin 1.4](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew14.html#explicit-api-mode-for-library-authors).

<s>This feature is only available in Kotlin 1.4, which is currently in the RC phase, but you can use the 1.4 version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin and 1.3.x version of the stdlib, to both benefit from the new Gradle plugin features and make sure your library doesn't depend on unstable 3rd party code.</s>

Example with Kotlin DSL (`build.gradle.kts`):

```
kotlin {   
   explicitApi() // for strict mode
   // or
   explicitApiWarning() // for warning mode
}
```

Example with Groovy DSL (`build.gradle`):

```
kotlin {   
   explicitApi = 'strict'
   // or
   explicitApi = 'warning'
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Hey @Endzeit, did you get it working? Because I get no errors (or warnings)..

Comment: Hello @elect. Yes, I did get it to work and added the required changes to the build.gradle.kts to Egors answer. Be sure to have Kotlin gradle plugin in version 1.4.x or above installed. I actually used 1.4.0-rc.

Comment: Yeah sorry, actually I was overwrite the compiler arguments instead appending..

Comment: I still can't get it working. @elect what have you done to fix set up?

Comment: Looks like here's the issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-37652.

Comment: I was replacing `freeCompilerArgs = listOf(..)` instead appending `freeCompilerArgs += listOf(..)`